# Dragging an object by touching Unity3d with android sdk

Tags: android, ios, touch, unity-game-engine, drag

I am trying to move and object by touching it and dragging. I am testing it on my Samsung Galaxy SIII. I have used the following code. For some reason it moves faster than my finger. It should always be beneath my finger. What is wrong? (note: I haven't done the "move object only if you touch onto it" part, so right now it moves where ever I touch).

```
#pragma strict

var speed : float = 1;

function Start () {

}

function Update () { 
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase ==     TouchPhase.Moved) {

    // Get movement of the finger since last frame
    var touchDeltaPosition:Vector2 = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;


    // Move object across XY plane
    transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position,
                                            touchDeltaPosition, 
                                            Time.deltaTime*speed);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what i use, it may be a better option for you, it is based on the camera, the reason that your Vector2.Lerp is not working correctly i think is because of your time variable in it you could refer to this [Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector2.Lerp.html) and tweak your 't' variable until it is good for you, or you can try this, this is what i use, also i subtract from x and add to y so my finger isnt over the graphic, best of luck :)

```
#pragma strict

var speed : float = 1;
var distance : float = 5;
function Start () {

}

function Update () { 
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase ==     TouchPhase.Moved) {

    // Get movement of the finger since last frame
    var touchDeltaPosition:Vector2 = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

    var touchmove : Vector3 = Vector3(touchDeltaPosition.x, touchDeltaPosition.y, distance);


    // Move object across XY plane
    transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchmove);
}
}
```

Comment: What is different? Why does this work, when the OP's code did not? Explaining this would make your answer better.